# Inequality proof as a part of calculus lesson

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

As part of a calculus lesson I was required to prove that:

(1) if $\ |x-3| < \frac{1}{2},\ $ then $\ \bigg|\displaystyle{\frac{\sin(x^2 -8x+15)}{4x-7}}\bigg| < \frac{1}{2}$

So, by using $|\sin(t)| \le |t|,$ I can prove that:
$$\bigg|\frac{\sin(x^2 -8x+15)}{4x-7}\bigg| \le \frac{5}{6}|x-3|$$
After proving this inequality I assume that the initial requirement is proved, and therefore I'm done, is that it or am I missing something?

Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: How did you justify the part "I proved that"?

Comment: Multiplying the denominator of the left part by both sides without changing the inequality sign, because it's in absolute value either due to the absolue value attributes. Doing some algebra by opening braces on the right section and simultaniously replacing the left section with the contect inside the braces of the Sin function, based on |sin(t)|≤|t| inequality.

Comment: After doing all I desctipted above I got two parabolas in absolute value which is one is above the other and they're intersecting twice, that's a property that always satisfies (sorry, don't know its exact name, like 1=1), based on it the initial assumption is satisfied too.

Comment: Regards @Ozk . If you have proved $$  \left| \frac{\sin(x^{2} - 8x + 15)}{4x-7} \right| \le |x-3| $$, then you are done. But I don't think that $ |4x - 7||x-3| = | x^{2} -8x + 15|  $.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just note $\sin x \leqslant 1$ and $|4x-7| > |4\cdot \frac52-7|=3 $ so $$\left|\frac{\sin(x^2-8x+15)}{4x-7}\right| < \frac13$$

Comment: Yes exactly, excellent :)

Answer (score 0):

Because, $x^{2}-8x+15=(x-3)(x-5)\ $, you can start saying that:

First,

$$ \vert{\sin(x^{2}-8x+15)}\vert\leq {x^{2}-8x+15} $$

and then you start like this

$$ \bigg\vert\frac{\sin(x^{2}-8x+15)}{4x-7}\bigg\vert=\frac{\vert{\sin(x^{2}-8x+15)}\vert}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}\leq\frac{\vert x^{2}-8x+15\vert}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}=\frac{\vert{(x-3)(x-5)}\vert}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}$$

Suppose that $\ \displaystyle{\vert{x-3}\vert<\frac{1}{2}}\ $, then

$$ -\frac{1}{2}<x-3<\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ 3-\frac{1}{2}<x<3+\frac{1}{2} $$

$$ \frac{5}{2}<x<\frac{7}{2} $$

and with the last condition you can bound $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}}$ and $\vert{x-5}\vert$. In fact,

$$ \frac{5}{2}<x<\frac{7}{2} \Rightarrow  \frac{5}{2}-5<x-5<\frac{7}{2}-5 $$

this means

$$ -\frac{5}{2}<x-5<-\frac{3}{2} $$

and the absolute value function is decreasing in the negatives real numbers:

$$ \frac{3}{2}<\vert{x-5}\vert<\frac{5}{2}, $$

so you have $$ \vert{x-5}\vert<\frac{5}{2}. $$

Also,

$$ \frac{5}{2}<x<\frac{7}{2} \Rightarrow 10<4x<14  \Rightarrow 3<4x-7<7$$

so $\vert{4x-7}\vert>3$ and this implies:

$$ \displaystyle{\frac{1}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}}<\frac{1}{3}. $$

Then you can multiply both inequalities below:

$$ \vert{x-5}\vert<\frac{5}{2} \qquad \displaystyle{\frac{1}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}}<\frac{1}{3}$$
to get:
$$ \frac{\vert{x-5}\vert}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}<\frac{5}{6}. $$

So,

$$ \bigg\vert\frac{\sin(x^{2}-8x+15)}{4x-7}\bigg\vert\leq\frac{\vert x^{2}-8x+15\vert}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}=\frac{\vert{(x-3)(x-5)}\vert}{\vert{4x-7}\vert}<\frac{5}{6}\vert{x-3}\vert<\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{12}<\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: See the comment to my post and my replies to it, is it acceptable to do it the graphic way like I did?

Comment: @Ozk: Yes, you can do it the graphic way for sure.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-You want to have $\dfrac52\lt x\lt \dfrac 72$ and your function $|f(x)|=\ \bigg|\displaystyle{\frac{\sin(x^2 -8x+15)}{4x-7}}\bigg| < \frac{1}{2}$ is

decreasing in this interval from $|f(\frac 52)|=|0.39952128217|$ till
$|f(\frac 72)|=|-0.102734043987|$